# Fetching and Displaying Timeline Data

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, react-fullstack

I need some advice here:

I am working on an application that is supposed to display data in a timeline view with `Weekly`, `Monthly` and `Yearly` options. I have two options that I'm torn between;

- I could fetch all the data at once and let the user interface display it in the timeline properly
- I could fetch data every time the user toggles into the next period e.g. when they change into the next month, fetch data for that time range

I need some counsel here on which is the best approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this whole thing in the back-end, and then take the processed data in the front-end. Make a database query with respect to the timestamp. Use offset concept if you doing pagination stuff. P.S - Please mention the database you are using.

Comment: Thanks @Souvik for the advice, I'm on a Postgres database.

Comment: Use OFFSET while using SELECT, this will help during pagination